# Regex error, use non-capturing groups instead

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring request mapped method in which I define regex for a path variable, but Spring throw exception when I test this method, what should I change?

```
@GetMapping("/items/item/{name:[a-zA-Z]+(\\s[a-zA-Z]+)*}")
public Item getItemByName(@PathVariable String name) {
    return itemService.getItemByName(name);
}
```

Error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The number of capturing groups in
>   the pattern segment ([a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z]+)*) does not match the
>   number of URI template variables it defines, which can occur if
>   capturing groups are used in a URI template regex. Use non-capturing
>   groups instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stacktrace it seems you should use the non capturing group.

Use `[a-zA-Z]+(?:\\s[a-zA-Z]+)*` instead `[a-zA-Z]+(\\s[a-zA-Z]+)*`

> > If you do not need the group to capture its match, you can optimize this regular expression into Set(?:Value)?.

**More details [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)**